# Copy file to user folder with a command line

Tags: windows, cmd, xcopy, robocopy

I have search the web high and low, but can not find away to copy a file to the desktop with a command line.

```
Xcopy File.exe c:/users/%username%/desktop
```

This gives me a error like

```
Access denied
```

I look in to robocopy also, with no luck.
Is there another program i can use?

Ps. I also tested

```
takeown /f <foldername> /r /d y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use backslashes for paths. Forward slash is switch and backslash is path separator.

Use `%userprofile%\desktop`. If the path is likely to have spaces enclose in quotes.

```
copy c:\windows\win.ini "%userprofile%\desktop\*.*"
```

**Reference**

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.

\\ (\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext) access files and folders via UNC naming.

: (win.ini:streamname) accesses an alternative steam. Also separates drive from rest of path.

. (win.ini) the LAST dot in a file path seperates the name from extension

. (dir .\*.txt) the current directory

.. (cd ..) the parent directory


\\?\ (\\?\c:\windows\win.ini) When a file path is prefixed with \\?\ filename checks are turned off. 

< > : " / \ | Reserved characters. May not be used in filenames.



Reserved names. These refer to devices eg, 

copy filename con 

which copies a file to the console window.

CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, 

COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, 

LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9



Maximum path length              260 characters
Maximum path length (\\?\)      32,767 characters (approx - some rare characters use 2 characters of storage)
Maximum filename length        255 characters


.
--
```

Comment: It worked . Do you have a answer to this also :   xcopy "master_preferences" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"     the same error

Comment: Always specify full paths. You are hoping `Master_Preferences` is a folder of the current directory (which will be different depending on how you start programs). Also it's wise to be clear. `c:\master_preferences\*.*` is better.